# Union merging different columns

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, union

I have two tables:

`Table1`:

```
DATAID|   NAME   | FACTOR

 1    |   Ann    |   1
 2    |   Kate   |   1
 3    |   Piter  |   1
```

`Table2`:

```
DATAID|   NAME   | FACTOR

 1    |   John    |   2
 6    |   Arse    |   2
 3    |   Garry   |   2
```

I would like `UNION` those tables and get this result:

```
DATAID|   NAME    | FACTOR

 1    |   Ann     |   1,2
 2    |   Kate    |   1
 3    |   Piter   |   1,2
 6    |   Arse    |   2
```

So when there's 2 rows with same dataid, I would like to get 'NAME' column from Table1 and some kind of aggregated FACTOR, for example '1,2' or 3

Comment: What happened to John and Garry from the second table?

Comment: that does not matter. Ann and Piter matter, John and Garry don't.

Comment: Then you don't want a UNION. Please clarify your requirement. Are you simply doing a UNION for (dataid, factor), and you choose the name from the first table if it exists, and if not, you take it from the second table?

Comment: And how is the query supposed to know that Ann and Piter matter, and that John and Garry don't? It appears you're taking John and Garry's FACTOR values and appending them to Ann and Piter's. How is the query supposed to determine this?

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `listagg()`:

```
select dataid, name,
       listagg(factor, ',') within group (order by factor) as factors
from ((select dataid, name, factor from table1 t1
      ) union all
      (select dataid, name, factor from table2 t2
      )
     ) t
group by dataid, name;
```

Note:  I notice that the names are *not* the same for a given id.  You can choose one by using aggregation functions.

Or, if you only have one row in each table, you can use a `full outer join`:

```
select coalesce(t1.dataid, t2.dataid) as dataid,
       coalesce(t1.name, t2.name) as name,
       trim(leading ',' from coalesce(',' || t1.factor, ',') || coalesce(',' || t2.factor, '') as factors
from t1 full outer join
     t2
     on t1.dataid = t2.dataid;
```

Comment: Did you notice that the union (or union all) of the OP's tables does not match his/her purported output?

Comment: [After your edits:] full outer join won't work, he/she has different names for the same id in the two tables, and wants to select what was in table1 first; an aggregate function won't work either (without extra work).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. In your actual situation you will not need the first two CTE's (the subqueries in the WITH clause I added for testing).

```
with 
     table1 ( dataid, name, factor ) as (
       select 1, 'Ann'  , 1 from dual union all
       select 2, 'Kate' , 1 from dual union all
       select 3, 'Piter', 1 from dual
     ),
     table2 ( dataid, name, factor ) as (
       select 1, 'John' , 2 from dual union all
       select 6, 'Arse' , 2 from dual union all
       select 3, 'Garry', 2 from dual
     ),
     u ( dataid, name, factor, source ) as (
       select dataid, name, factor, 1 from table1
       union all
       select dataid, name, factor, 2 from table2
     ),
     z ( dataid, name, factor ) as (
       select dataid, first_value(name) over (partition by dataid order by source), 
              factor
       from   u
     )
select dataid, name,
       listagg(factor, ',') within group (order by factor) as factor
from   z
group by dataid, name
order by dataid
;
```

Output:

```
 DATAID NAME  FACTOR
------- ----- ---------
      1 Ann   1,2
      2 Kate  1
      3 Piter 1,2
      6 Arse  2

4 rows selected.
```